# How to make array from properties of elements of list?

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays, list

Is there a succint way in vb.net to create an array or similar of each of the properties in a list?

E.g. If I have a list of 'a' and each 'a' has a property 'b', I want to create an array which contains all the 'b's, in the same index positions as the original list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List.select( function(x) x.property )
```

Comment: Perhaps with the caveat that if the OP gets enthusiastic and tries using .AsParallel, then .AsOrdered would be needed too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460677%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an array of [IDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.aspx)?

The instance of IDictionary will hold key/value pairs.  If you make an array of IDictionary, then each element in the array will be the unique property set for each list of 'a'.